# Duostack vs. Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paas, duostack

I know this is not a really programmic question, but which one should I deploy my app too?
Basically, I will have a straight forward Rails app with a a decent database usage. Heroku is obviously a great platform and has a lot of gimmicks. Duostack however seems to getting bigger and bigger while still in beta, and I really like their autoscaling feature, since I wouldn't have to monitor my site like 24/7 to be as cost efficient as possible.
Secretly, I just hope that Amazon will extend Elastic to Rails, but that would probably take a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to get an invite to use Duostack, I don't know how hard that is. Plus, if you're looking to do a production app, they're still in Beta so there's no 100% guarantee things will be stable, or that there won't be API changes.

ALso, is duostack going to offer a free usage tier?

If you're comfortable with the answers to all those questions, then just go for whichever one you like better.

One nice thing about Heroku is it is well-established enough to have a lot of third party integration, and that can make development just blissful if it includes the integrations you need :)

Probably not a wrong choice between the two, though. Request a beta invite and if you get in, try both. Since all you have to do is "git push" to deploy to both, it ought to be pretty easy to do a direct side-by-side comparison of the workflow.

Comment: Yes, Duostack has stated that there will always be a free tier of service available. (Disclosure: I work at Duostack.)

Comment: @tfe -- awesome, perhaps you can speak to how hard it is to get a beta invite? I haven't tried as I don't have a serious production app ready to deploy, but I've been quite curious to test duostack out...

Comment: @Andrew (et al.): Go ahead and sign up; it shouldn't take long: http://dstk.wufoo.com/forms/duostack-beta-access/

Comment: just signed up - really interested in taking a peak at duostack :)

Comment: i mean i am already in the beta, i am just debating whether I should actually use it, since there were some points I wasn't sure about. Also, I dont know how much I am allowed to communicate about that, but yeah, there are definitely some points that could turn me back to heroku

Comment: Well look -- let me put it this way: if it's time for you to deploy NOW, then use Heroku. Heroku is out of beta so you know there won't be an API changes that will possibly derail your app. Duostack *probably* won't do that, but they can't truly guarantee that, that's why they're calling it a Beta :) If you're still going to be developing for a while though, just use whichever you prefer. There isn't a right or wrong choice, just a matter of preference.

Comment: It only took me a day to get my invite.